# Object does not source automation events on Office.CommandBarButton object (Excel for Mac 2016)

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am using the code described in [this post](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/CatchPaste.asp) to try to capture paste events and force them to Paste Special to preserve my validation. As part of that code, there is a class module:

```
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Module    : clsCommandBarCatch
' Company   : JKP Application Development Services (c)
' Author    : Jan Karel Pieterse
' Created   : 4-10-2007
' Purpose   : This class catches clicks on Excel's commandbars to be able to prevent pasting.
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents oComBarCtl As Office.CommandBarButton '<- Error highlights this line

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set oComBarCtl = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub oComBarCtl_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, CancelDefault As Boolean)
    CancelDefault = True
    Application.OnTime Now, "MyPasteValues"
End Sub
```

However, I can't get the code to run because I keep getting the compile error

> Object does not source automation events

highlighting the line indicated above.

I have checked my references, in the "Add References" window of my VBA editor (I am on Excel for Mac 2016 btw) and found the following libraries checked:

- Visual Basic for Applications
- Microsoft Excel 14.0 Objects
- Microsoft Office 14.0 Objects
- Microsoft Forms 2.0 Objects

I also checked "OLE Automation" just in case. There are some other libraries not checked ("VBAProject", "EBApp Object Library", libraries for other Office apps) that don't seem to apply here so I left them unchecked.

I also tested this on Excel for Mac 2011 and got the same error. Is it possible newer versions of Excel don't use the `CommandBar` object b/c of the Ribbon?

Any thoughts on how to clear this error are appreciated.

Comment: Well it's simple: you can't have a `WithEvents` object of type `Office.CommandBarButton`, because it's not an automation events source. And yes, CommandBar API has been obsolete since the Ribbon came along. Can you test it on a non-Mac machine?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I don't have a non-Mac machine unfortunately. I might know someone who could test it. What would you recommend using in place of Office.CommandBarButton? Is there a different object to call the Ribbon?

Comment: Ribbon is a completely different thing, and I've no idea about the limited API on a Mac. Good luck!